# Error en el IF EXISTS en postgresSQL: "ERROR: la consulta no tiene un destino para los datos de resultado"

Tags: postgresql, sql, function, pgadmin

## ¿Cuál es mi error?

**Me dice que las consultas dentro del if necesitan Return, pero solo quiero verificar si existe un valor similar dentro de una tabla en la BD, los valores que quiero retornar ya están con su return query en la parte inferior y ya lo intenté usando el INTO asignándole una variable.**

He estado tratando de validar si existen registros similares en algunas de las tablas, dado que mi consulta lo que hace es insertar en mi tabla paciente en mi aplicación y retornar un valor para actualizar mi tabla de pacientes, pero me da el error en los IF, pues necesita que retorne un valor después del select, lo había intentado con los IF EXISTS pero me da el mismo error.
Además intenté declarar 2 valores, pero al parecer debo retornar algo después de la consulta en el IF

```
create function fnNuevRegistro
(input_xml xml)
returns table(validX text)
as
$$
DECLARE root_xpath TEXT = '/MascotaREG/';
begin 

IF (select count(*) from especie_paciente where 
nombrevulgarespecie = ((xpath(root_xpath||'especieM/text()', input_xml))[1])::text) >0
THEN select '1';
else                             
insert into especie_paciente (especiepacienteid, nombrevulgarespecie) 
values ((select count(*) from especie_paciente)::int +1, 
((xpath(root_xpath||'especieM/text()', input_xml))[1]::text));
                  end IF;


        
if(select count(*) from raza_especie where nombreraza =
((xpath(root_xpath||'raza/text()', input_xml))[1])::text) >0
      THEN select '1';
       else
       insert into raza_especie (razaespecieid, nombreraza) values
       ((select count(*) from raza_especie)::int +1,
((xpath(root_xpath||'raza/text()', input_xml))[1])::text);
        end IF;
insert into paciente values 
((select count(*) from paciente)::int +1,
((xpath(root_xpath||'nombreM/text()',input_xml))[1])::text,
case when ((xpath(root_xpath||'generoM/text()',input_xml))[1])::text= 'Masculino' then 'M' else 'F' end,
cast( ((xpath(root_xpath||'edadM/text()',input_xml))[1])::text as integer ) ,
(select cl.clienteid from persona p inner join cliente cl on cl.personaid = p.personaid
where p.email = ((xpath(root_xpath||'usuarioLg/text()', input_xml))[1])::text),
(select especiepacienteid from especie_paciente where nombrevulgarespecie = 
 ((xpath(root_xpath||'especieM/text()', input_xml))[1])::text),
(select razaespecieid from raza_especie where nombreraza = 
 ((xpath(root_xpath||'raza/text()',input_xml))[1])::text
), 'FOTO'
);
return query
select case when nombrepaciente =
((xpath(root_xpath||'nombreM/text()', input_xml))[1])::text then 'Bien' 
else 'Mal' end as ValidadorX from paciente
where nombrepaciente =((xpath(root_xpath||'nombreM/text()', input_xml))[1]);          
end;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Salida
`ERROR: la consulta no tiene un destino para los datos de resultado.`
`Hint: Si quiere descartar los resultados de un SELECT, utilice PERFORM.`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error se debe al "SELECT '1';" que está en el primer y segundo IF, luego del THEN (cuando la condición es verdadera), el resultado de esa query no se utiliza para nada. Deberías cambiar la condición y sacar el ELSE.

Solo falla cuando llamas a la función y la condición es verdadera (e ingresa al THEN), si la condición es falsa no falla porque ingresa al ELSE.

Podrías modificar el IF de está forma:

```
IF (SELECT count(*) FROM especie_paciente where nombrevulgarespecie = ((xpath(root_xpath||'especieM/text()', input_xml))[1])::text) = 0 THEN          
    INSERT INTO especie_paciente (especiepacienteid, nombrevulgarespecie) VALUES ((SELECT count(*) FROM especie_paciente)::int +1, ((xpath(root_xpath||'especieM/text()', input_xml))[1]::text));
END IF;
```

También podrías usar PERFORM, pero me parece que no tiene sentido en este caso.

Te recomiendo que no pongas la query como condición del IF, para que sea mas legible el código, en su lugar guardá el resultado de la query en una varaible.

Para ello primero tenés que declarar la variable en la sección DECLARE:

```
DECLARE
  cantidad INTEGER;
```

y luego guardar el count(*) en la variable cantidad:

```
SELECT count(*) INTO cantidad
FROM raza_especie WHERE nombreraza =
((xpath(root_xpath||'raza/text()', input_xml))[1])::text;
```